# Image formatted as text decoding

Tags: json, image, photo, data-conversion

I'm poking around a relatively undocumented database and I've found what purports to be a photo encoded as text? I'd love to be able to identify what format it is so I can convert them and see the image.

The field name in the JSON was 'photo', but I have no idea how it's encoded and I can't find a way to google it either.
Below is one of the images as text in question.

```
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00\x1a\x00\x14\x00\x00\xff\xfe\x00!LENEL OnGuard Chromakey=23,3,30\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x08\x05\x06\x07\x06\x05\x08\x07\x06\x07\t\x08\x08\t\x0c\x13\x0c\x0c\x0b\x0b\x0c\x18\x11\x12\x0e\x13\x1c\x18\x1d\x1d\x1b\x18\x1b\x1a\x1f#,%\x1f!*!\x1a\x1b&4\'*./121\x1e%6:60:,010\xff\xdb\x00C\x01\x08\t\t\x0c\n\x0c\x17\x0c\x0c\x170 \x1b 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\xff\xc0\x00\x11\x08\x00P\x00<\x03\x01!\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01\xff\xc4\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x01\x04\x03\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x02\x04\x05\x07\x00\x01\x03\x08\xff\xc4\x003\x10\x00\x02\x01\x03\x02\x04\x03\x07\x03\x04\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x00\x04\x11\x05!\x06\x121A\x07\x13\x81\x14"QRaq\xa12\xb1\xc1#3\xd1\xe1Cr\x91\xff\xc4\x00\x19\x01\x00\x03\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x00\x04\x05\xff\xc4\x00\x1e\x11\x00\x03\x01\x01\x01\x00\x03\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x11!\x03\x12"1AQ\xff\xda\x00\x0c\x03\x01\x00\x02\x11\x03\x11\x00?\x00)\rK\rS\x08\xc3[\xd7\xf4\xcd\x06\xd8O\xaa\xdd$\n\xdf\xa1N\xec\xff\x00\xf5Q\xb9\xa0\xab\xbf\x18\xb4\xe5b-4\xcb\xa9Tt.\xca\x99\xfd\xe9\x920\xa8\xbc`\xb0i\xe3V\xb1\x99"8\xe6c\x82W\xd3\xbf\xa5X\x9a^\xa1m\xa9\xd9\xc7ug*\xcb\x14\x802\xb2\x9c\x82(\x80wY\x8a\x06"CTo\x13\xeb\xd0\xf0\xfe\x8bq\x7f0\xe6(1\x1a|\xeez\nD1\xe7\xdd[V\xbb\xd65\tou\t\x8c\xd3\xcaw\'\xa0\x1d\x80\x1d\x80\xf8V\xac\xac\xe6\xb8\xdd\x10\x95\x07s\xda\xa8\xde $\xdb\xc4j\xfe\x17\xb7\xb8a"\x95\x0cr(\xdf\xc2N*\x93J\xd5\x97K\xb9rm/\x1b\t\x9f\xf8\xe4\xed\x8f\xa3t?\\\x1a\xcb\xa8\xcdc\xc2\xf1V\x0c\xa0\x83\x90w\x14\xac\xd0\x01\n\x1f\x15Tx\xcf\xab4\xda\x8d\xa6\x97\x1be O5\xc0\xf9\x9b\xa7\xfe\x0f\xde\x92\x7fF`\xde\x8b\xa6\xc4\x80<\xf0\xac\xb2\x1d\xf0\xdb\x85\xa2\x1b~TnU\x89W=\xb1S\xaa\xd6uD\xfcP\xd3Z\xb0[\xcbv^P\x1cn\xbfz\x0eS-\xad\xc6\xc4\xa4\x910`~\x04\x1d\xaa\xbeo\x98C\xd5wOK\xf0\x9e\xa6\xba\xb7\x0f\xd9^\xa9\xdeh\x830\xf87\x7f\xcej_4\xc4\x88\x1el\x0c\xd5\x17\xc5\xceo8\xe6\xf3\x9c\x92\r\xc0O@\x00\xfe)$a\x13\xeaW\x10\xc9\xcb\x01\x18\x07\x97\x02.\xff\x00|\xe6\xa4\x12\xf6\xe5\xf4\xdfiX\xceF\xd9\xc7zW(\xbc\xdb\xea\x1bZ\xeawl\xe4\\K6\xc4{\xa25\xc6\xfd6\xc6\xf4\xc7\x89m\xbc\xbb\x88\xa6Q\xfd\xd5\xdfn\xe2\x9dq\x93\xa6\xda\xe9k\xf8%v\xd3p\xb3\xc2I>\xcf; \xfa\x03\x86\xfej\xc1\rLH\x80v\xc0\xaa?\x88\x7f\xa5\xc7wx\xdc\x0b\xa2})\x17\xf4bZ\xe5t\xe4\x8c\xcd*\x13(\xdb\x01\x8e\t\xfbS\xd8\xa4\x85t\xc5Q\xc8\xcd\x92Y2?\x15,gf$"\xc8im\x99 \x88+\xfc\xa4\x9d\xbd*+\x89\x07\x9d#0\x1e\xecP\xb3\xfd\xbb\ny_\xe9?L\xce\x06>\x05M\x8d/R\x88\xf6\x9d\x18z\xa9\xff\x00\x15f\xf3\xd5NPv\xe6nU5Hq\x8b\xb2\xf1]\xfb\x83\xef\t\xb2\x08\xfb\nY\x19\x8fp\'1\\\xc0\xca\xe5\x86y[\xa0\xff\x00u)kc\n\x11)\x9a z\x81\xe59\xc7\xa7\xe9\xfc\xd2\xa4t\xae\xff\x004\xe6 "\xf4\xcd;(c\x9d\x90`\x11\xdb?Z\x1e\xe2+\xcf?Pt\x89\xcf\x96\x8a\x10\xe0\xecM\x19\xeb\'\xe9\xc4Y\xde\x0bY\xb4\x1a\r\xcd\xdbl.%\xc2\xfd\x97\xfd\x9a?\xe6\xa7 \x07\xcf\x7f\x14\xe5\x84.\x1c\x8e\xa0v\xdf\x1f\xb8"\xa9\xbe!\x94O\xad\xdeH\x180i[q\xde\x84\x85\x8b\xd1\xaeZ7(\xd9h\xfa\xe3\xe1\xf6\xa9\xdb{\x8d0\x1ew2\xf3u\xfe\xe1\x1f\x8aJOx_\xcd\xac\xe8\x8b\xbb\xbf8\x9f \x14\x8c\x0e\xa6\x85\x9c\xe6F?\x12M4,\'}\r\xfc>\xe3\x11\xa2)\xb3\xbec\xec\x84\xe5O^C\xdf\xd2\xad\x0b^!\xd3\xaeaY`\xbb\x85\xd0\xf4!\xc510+T\xe05\x96\xf2{\x88/\xee\x90\xcc\xec\xea\x91\x80\x15\t\xeb\xbeh\x03R\xd0/l\xe6th_\xdcb\xa7=i\x9f\xd7\xf4\xd3\xf6\xfc:X\xd8\xb4`\x13\xd4\xf5\xa7\x9e\xc5\xce\xdb.\xf5\xce\xebY\xd2\xa7\x98;[\x12`*F20j\x0eM\x12\xe0\xbb\x18\x80#\xa8\x07\xe1Fk?E\xa9\xd5\xc1\x84\xb6\xf3\xa4\xdeT\x912\xbf\xcb\x8a\xeb\r\x8d\xdc\xc9\xcf\r\xb4\x8e\xbd2\xaaqV z\x1c "\xa3\xb5]\x1a\x1b\xe5\xe6a\xcb \x18\x0e\x06}\x08\xefV\xa8\xf9,\'\x17\xf1z\t\xdfp\xdd\xcc.H\x80\xb2|\xd1\x8ea\xf8\xae0\xd9\xac?\xa8`\xfdEy\xf75/\x19\xe8K\x9a\xea\x1cG\xa7\xc9pyb\x85\xdc\x9f\x95I\xa9-?\x84\xdc\x9ek\xa7\x11\x8f\x95}\xe6\xff\x00\x02\x9f\xcf\xca\xac_OI\x80\x86\xd7B\xd3\xe0\x8b\x91m\x91\x89\x18,\xe3\x99\x9b\xee\x7f\x8au\x05\x8d\xb5\xacK\x0c\x11$Q\xafEQ\x80+\xbdJK\x11\xe7\xbat\xf5\x98\x84`R\xe8\x98\xd1PNq\xbf\xc6\xb3\x90\x1f\x8f\xa9\xcd\x10\n\xe5\x18\xc6\xe4}M(\n\xc6:\x0f\xd4\x07\xadq\x98\x90\xf4L\x7f\xff\xd9'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a JPEG file. You can find out easily by writing the data to a file and using the `file` command:

```
$ python
>>> fp = open('test', 'wb+')
>>> fp.write(b'[..your data..]')
>>> fp.close()
>>> ^D

$ file test
test: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 26x20,
segment length 16, comment: "LENEL OnGuard Chromakey=23,3,30", baseline,
precision 8, 60x80, frames 3

$ mv test test.jpg
$ pqiv test.jpg 
[.. I see a lady ..]
```

Or you could've used the [mime-magic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic/) library if you want a Python-only solution.

In fact, all of that is overkill, because just converting it to a string and viewing it with a text editor shows:

```
<FF><D8><FF><E0>^@^PJFIF
```

At the start (JFIF being usual JPEG image format, for PNG files it shows "PNG" at the start).

Comment: Hey thanks, that worked perfectly. I should've recognized the PJIF in the header, I definitely will next time.